# Where can I find the best fonts online?

Tags: fonts, freelance

Sites like Font Squirrel and Space Fonts have some good type faces, but every time I see an effective logo it always has this stellar font that fits the image perfectly. I'm wondering 'where is everyone getting these jaw-dropping fonts?'for cheap or practically free? I don't feel like paying 200$ for a font. That's basically what I charge for logos. Where exactly can I find great fonts?

Comment: Typically if you want something for free, it's not the best quality. And high-quality logos often involve editing letterforms and a bit more than merely choosing a font.

Comment: If you are using Adobe's recent Creative Cloud software, there's a large collection of quality fonts from Typekit that are included in with your plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyFonts sells all the pro expensive stuff, but if you use the advanced search you can get plenty of good quality fonts in the 5-10$ range, try it out.

- https://www.myfonts.com/search//search/fonts/?sort=cheap

Answer (score 1):

There are some sites with relative good quality free fonts included in these answers:

[Google Font for the Caviar Dreams font](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/116049/120647)

[Open Source alternatives to FF Tisa fonts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/117247/120647)